# Altering Domain Entities When Changing Persistence Layer

Tags: c#, oop

In my app, I've been using a DB that stored its IDs as strings. The DB also stored another property (Etag) for each document/row. Because of that, I've had my domain entities derive from this base class:

```
public class EntityBase : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm adding another data layer to my application, and I don't want to remove the old one. It would be nice to be able to switch and use a particular data layer based on a run-time decision. The issue is that I want to store Id as an int in the new DB. And ETag is an unnecessary concept in that new DB.

I'm struggling with how to manage this change. If I change EntityBase.Id to an int, then the old data layer won't compile. I'd like to use a certain EntityBase if using the old data layer, and a different EntityBase if I'm using the new data layer. That's just one thought. Maybe there's a better approach? Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

By the way, I believe that persistence layer issues shouldn't work there way up into domain layer objects (like Id being a string or int). However, it's too late, and this is the situation in which I find myself. I'm hoping someone has some good advice on how to proceed.

I was thinking about adding an Id2 to EntityBase:

```
public class EntityBase : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }  // New property for new DB only
    public Guid ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my new DAL mapping, I would map the Id column in the table to Id2 instead of Id. But that's not going to work because my business logic references Id only. Still thinking... I may be stuck...

As a hack, I could leave EntityBase in its original form. Then, in the new DAL, when I perform the ORM, I could just convert the ID of the table to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add one more layer then.
For instance, to create a new class like this:

```
public abstract class CommonEntityBase<T> : NotifyPropertyChangedBase{
    public T Id {get;set;} 
}
```

And then, derive your old EntityBase from this class:

```
public class EntityBase : CommonEntityBase<string>{

    //this property is present only in this old implementation
    public Guid ETag { get; set; }
}
```

So now, you can create a new layer and use a base class for that as well:

```
public class FancyEntityBase : CommonEntityBase<int>{
    //No ETag concept here - ad new properties, methods, etc.
}
```

However, there is a question if you really need to change your primary keys to be integers.
This may result in performance issues when the ORM is used.

Comment: With this approach, I think I still have an issue though. What do my domain entities derive from? With this solution, don't I need to change the base class based on which persistence layer is used? For example, Foo would derive from EntityBase when using one DAL, and Foo would derive from FancyEntityBase when using another DAL. That changes the hierarchy at compile-time. No?

Comment: I do not think that deriving Domain Entities from DAL entities is a good idea - you're tightly coupling them together and that's why you're having this problem now (this is an OCP violation). If you had a "de-coupled" code, you could have used the Dependency Injection approach combined with DI Container and inject different object graphs at your composition root based on run-time decision (which is probably a version number in your case - isn't it?). Unfortunately, I do not see an easy way to fix it. The domain should be decoupled from database concerns first.

Comment: I think you're right; once I originally made the decision to let anything from the data layer creep into the domain model, that is the true problem. To fix this issue, I need to remove that obstacle. Thanks.